# Selnium WebDriver Error specs

Tags: ruby, testing, selenium, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver

trying to run the tests I get the next error

```
Failure/Error: sign_in @user
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
     unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)
```

Gemfile:

```
ruby "2.0.0"
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.1'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'annotate', :git => 'git://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.38.0'
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

Other specs:

- Mozilla Firefox 33.0
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Trying to fix this reinstalling & updating the gem 'selenium-webdriver' .

NOTE: **I get a new laptop and the project working fine in the old one.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Firefox 33, you should update the `selenium-webdriver` gem to the most current version, which is 2.43.  Update your gemfile accordingly and run `bundle install`.